# Why i can't read the text file using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<script>$(function() {
    var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
        //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        var lines = txt.split("\n");
        $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
            $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>');
        }
        //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
        $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
            row_height: 48,
            max_rows: 2,
            speed: 6000,
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 1000,
            autostart: 1,
            pauseOnHover: 1
        });
    });
});

    autostart: 1,
    pauseOnHover: 0
});
</script>
```

The links exist and not give 404 not found.
But i don't see the lines from the text file being reading.

I clicked on my site Ctrl+Shist+C in the Audits tab i see one error:

Unexpected token: test.html:120 i click on it and there is one empty line thats it.
And i'm not using and dont have any file called test.html

The goal is that the jquery will read each time one or two lines and scroll it up.

This is the site:

http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code is malformed. Remove this from your javascript:

```
    autostart: 1,
    pauseOnHover: 0
});
```

Comment: @Marty Word `crap` is not allowed to mention? Even if it's crap? :)

Comment: Not sure to be honest :S

Answer (score 1):

You should remove this obsolete code from the end of your function:

```
});

autostart: 1,
pauseOnHover: 0
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8UR5/)